# Arrange value in data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

```
T
-----
2016m1
2016m10
2016m11
2016m12
2016m2
2016m3
2016m4
2016m5
2016m6
2016m7
2016m8
2016m9
```

I want to arrange this table, like table below.

```
T
-----
2016m1
2016m2
2016m3
2016m4
2016m5
2016m6
2016m7
2016m8
2016m9
2016m10
2016m11
2016m12
```

So anybody can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or using base-R where your data vector is *T*:

```
T[order(sapply(T, function(l) as.integer(substr(l, 6, nchar(l)+1))))]
```

Answer (score 3):

With `mixedsort` from `gtools`:

```
library(gtools)
df$T <- mixedsort(df$T)
```

or `mixedorder`:

```
df$T <- df$T[mixedorder(df$T)]
```

**Output:**

```
         T
1   2016m1
2   2016m2
3   2016m3
4   2016m4
5   2016m5
6   2016m6
7   2016m7
8   2016m8
9   2016m9
10 2016m10
11 2016m11
12 2016m12
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(T = c("2016m1", "2016m10", "2016m11", "2016m12", 
"2016m2", "2016m3", "2016m4", "2016m5", "2016m6", "2016m7", "2016m8", 
"2016m9")), .Names = "T", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `regex` with `gsub` is something like this:

Assuming that `T` is a `data.frame`

```
last_digits <- as.numeric(gsub("[0-9]{4}m","",T[,1]))
T[order(last_digits),] #Ordered dataframe
```

**Regex explanation**

`[0-9]{4}m` Looks for exactly 4 digits, if you want to use a range of numbers you can use `{num_1-num_2}`, after finding the "rule" then it will look for the letter `m`.